# Proper way to create a node alias that is the filename

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm using a FileFeild Image field to get an image and then I'm using [File (Field) Paths](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_paths) to rename the file to random characters.

**What I'm trying to do**

- Image content type
- Has an FileField Image, field_image
- Upload image with content type, example.jpg
- example.jpg is renamed to Ax54jk.jpg (File Field Paths)
- mysite.com/node/523 is altered to mysite.com/Ax54jk

**Problem**

The image does get renamed with [File (Field) Paths](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_paths) and that works perfectly. The trouble is that I can't get the node to rename to match the newly renamed filename.

**What I've tried**

I've tried to use Pathauto where I set a pattern for the Image content type of `[node:field_image]`, Pathauto fails to add an alias on initial node creation. I suspect this has to do with the order of the hook calls.

I also tried this hook

```
function MYMODULE_node_insert($node) {
 if ($node->type == 'image') {
   $filename = $node->field_image['und'][0]['filename'];
   // do stuff
   $node->path['alias'] = $result;
 }
}
```

In this hook, `$node->field_image` doesn't seem to have all of the file data at this point and is not yet available.

**Question**

Does anyone know how to do this, even if I write a custom module? What hooks will allow me to do this?

Is there a way to get the file name with [Custom Tokens](http://drupal.org/project/custom_tokens) instead?

**Answer**

I eventually tracked down in the File (Field) Paths code a hook to implement and using @Clive's code below, I was able to create an alias. I created a module to do this because File (Field) Paths doesn't appear to work directly with Pathauto.

`hook_filefield_paths_process_file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node has already been saved in `hook_node_insert()`/`hook_node_update()` which is why your changes aren't being reflected.

Fortunately there's [`hook_node_presave()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7). If you put your code in that hook it should work.

The file field will only contain the ID of the file so you'll need to load that object to get the filename:

```
$items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_image');
if ($items) {
  $file = file_load($items[0]['fid']);
  $filename = $file->filename;
  // ...
}
```

If you install the [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module, though, you'll be able to assign a pattern to the image node type which contains the image field's filename without any code at all.

Comment: The issue I have is with Pathauto unfortunately. If you know how to fix it, I'll be glad to try it. If not I'll try the hook you've suggested.

Comment: I've implemented the hook and it does allow me to set the alias as the filename just like you suggested. However, it sets the alias as mysite.com/example.jpg and not to the renamed filename from FileField Paths of mysite.com/Ax54jk.jpg. Any suggestions for this?

Comment: I found a hook for File (Field) Paths that let me use your code to do the updating. I'm accepting your answer since it would have taken me a decade to figure out how to do the file loading you did in the code.

Comment: Good stuff glad you got it sorted